Generate a public/private key pair in Privacy Enhanced Mail (PEM) format for the MDM server, and store the private key securely on the server
I am trying to follow the instructions for creating DEP Server Tokens in Apple's Device Enrollment Program manual (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/device_assignment/authenticating_with_a_device_enrollment_program_dep_server) , i don't know which certifacte need to upload for cread mdm server.
and after getin .p7m mdm server token how can i use this
upload certificate(PEM/DER)(https://i.sstatic.net/Jp9y1vE2.png)

After getting a server token from ABM you need to follow some steps to extract information from token.
step 1. Clean the data : command ->
grep -Eo '[A-Za-z0-9+/=]+' smime.p7m > cleaned_smime.p7m
step 2. Base64 Decode : command ->
base64 -d cleaned_smime.p7m > decoded_test_smime.p7m
step 3. Decrypt the data using your private key and cert key : command ->
openssl smime -decrypt -in decoded_test_smime.p7m -inform DER -inkey private_key.pem -certfile cert_key.pem -out extracted_content.txt
After completing this steps you get a extracted data into extracted_content.txt file.
